# Report in MS Project (Hr/task/resource)

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, reporting

I am trying to find/create a report in MS Project 2013 in order to display hours done in a month by a certain group of resource or a resource only (they are already grouped in the Allocation tab) with the tasks they are assigned to. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use "resource usage" view and change the timescale to months.

You can group by "resource type" or "resource type" in the view ribbon.